# Get Geographical Coordinates from address in Python 2

Tags: python, geolocation

I'm using `Pycharm 2.2 community`, currently trying to get `latitude` and `longitude` from addresses. Stored the address data in a panda data frame and tried to get its geographical coordinates. However, it returned me:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/map.py", line 19, in <module>
  geocode_result = gmaps_key.geocode(data1.iat[i, 0])" and "return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)" after execution.
```

When hover over geocode, the tooltip returns me `"unresolved attribute reference 'geocode'` for class `'Client'`..."

Below is my code, any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import googlemaps

data = pd.read_csv("listing.csv", usecols=['building_no', 'street_name'])
# df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
data['address'] = data[['building_no', 'street_name']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
data1 = data['address']
# print data1

# Set google map API key
gmaps_key = googlemaps.Client(key="AIzaSyDjB0HJolcomNZCWrtq9gef70V4F2xtB_s")

# create Geocode result object
# get LON and LAT
data1["LAT"] = None
data1["LON"] = None

for i in range(0, len(data1), 1):
    geocode_result = gmaps_key.geocode(data1.iat[i, 0])
    try:
        lat = geocode_result[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
        lon = geocode_result[0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
        data1.iat[i, data1.columns.get_loc("LAT")] = lat
        data1.iat[i, data1.columns.get_loc("LON")] = lon
    except:
        lat = None
        lon = None

print data1
```